# highcharts with year selector

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts for my statistics, I made a extra button for selecting a year. This works fine but when i click the button it refresh the page and that's not what I want.

My Highcharts series looks like this:

```
series: [{
     name: 'Sales <? echo $year; ?>',
     lineWidth: 4,
     lineColor: '#058DC7',
     color: '#058DC7',
     marker : {
        enabled : true,
        fillColor: '#058DC7',
        radius : 5,
        lineWidth : 2,
        states: {
            hover: {
                radius: 6,
                lineWidth : 2
                }
            }
        },
    states: {
    hover: {
        lineWidth: 5
        }
     },
     data: [<?

        //SELECT FROM DATABASE
        $query = "SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount_total
        FROM invoices 
        WHERE user_id = {$_COOKIE['customer_id']} 
        AND date BETWEEN '{$year}-01-01' AND '{$year}-12-30'
        GROUP BY MONTH(date)";
        $sql = mysql_query("$query"); 
        while ($fill = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
        { 
            $amount = $fill['amount'];

            echo $amount.',';
        }

        ?>]

  }
```

The button:

```
    <div class="stats_options" id="yearSelector" style="margin-bottom:10px; width:150px;">Select Year: <span style="color:#058DC7; font-weight:bold;">2008</span></div>
      <div id="yearSelectorOptions" class="option_list" style="width:170px; display:none;">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="?config&year=2009&history=">2009</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=2008&history=">2008</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=2007&history=">2007</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=2006&history=">2006</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=2005&history=">2005</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=2004&history=">2004</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=2003&history=">2003</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=2002&history=">2002</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=2001&history=">2001</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=2000&history=">2000</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=1999&history=">1999</a></li><li><a href="?config&year=1998&history=">1998</a></li>                                
          </ul>
      </div>
```

So i want to change the year without refreshing te page.

I hope someone can help me in the right direction!

Comment: If you do not want the page to refresh then you need to do Ajax request on the click of the button and the update the chart with the data in the response.

Answer (score 1):

As Bhesh noted, you'll need Ajax to perform the update. I have created something similar here: http://danaben.net/t/baseball/scatter.php

Check out the script at the top which sets some chart options, gets the selected year, and then calls a php script. The php returns a json object which I use to replace the options.series value. You'll have to tailor this to your chart, but this should be in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! This will put me in the right direction, do you have an example of your php file? Sorry for asking...